# Making a sprite appear for half a second or so and then disappear

Tags: java, android, android-animation, sprite, game-development

I am writing a simple Android "space" game, and would like to add - for half a second or so - an "explosion" sprite when the player ship and the enemy ship collide, to give the effect of an explosion taking place. This is based on a simple PNG image, with no animation or else, but as I wrote it should suddenly appear at the collision coordinates, and disappear very soon. Maybe half a second or so. How can I do that? Are there "visible" and "invisible" properties (or similar) for sprites in Android Studio? I am a bit inexperienced, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CountdownTimer with setVisibility()

like this:

```
 new CountDownTimer(500, 500) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
 }

 public void onFinish() {
        imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
 }
 }.start();
```

about Countdowntimer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I have to integrate this code with the sprite's code, so that the sprite is visible and invisible. In other words, I have to create a method for the sprite to become visible and invisible.

Comment: Is imageview.setVisibility() a sprite’s property?

Comment: For an explosion, I'd progressively increase the alpha in `onTick()`. This would give the impression of something suddenly appearing and slowly vanishing. As I expect a fire and smoke ball would do in real life. Other than this, alternating some frames (2 would do the trick) would work even better.

Comment: Sure. But I decided for very simple effects in this game. But I cannot implement setVisibility() with my sprite.

Comment: You appear to be confused: Why do you call an ImageView a "sprite"? A sprite is a bitmap. An ImageView is a container object. A place where to draw a bitmap.

Comment: I understand, but I have a .PNG image that represents the explosion, in other words my sprite. How do I use ImageView to implement the desired behavior on my sprite? I am a beginner so yes I am a bit confused.

Comment: You can set the alpha value of the ImageView after setting an image (the explosion) into it. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageAlpha(int)

Comment: I followed suggestions on this site, so I pasted my .PNG image in the drawable folder, and wrote this code: ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.explosion);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.explosion); But Android Studio gives me this error message: "Cannot resolve symbol 'setImageResource'". I am really a bit confused, perhaps it's better that I make it without this effect.